# Sum with SQL server RollUP - but only last summary?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, rollup

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),datee date,val money)

insert INTO @t SELECT 'a','2012-01-02',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a','2012-01-02',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a','2012-01-03',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a','2012-01-05',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'b','2012-01-06',200
insert INTO @t SELECT 'b','2012-01-07',200
insert INTO @t SELECT 'd','2012-01-07',400
insert INTO @t SELECT 'e','2012-01-09',500
insert INTO @t SELECT 'f','2012-01-12',600

SELECT  Name,datee,SUM (val) 
from @t GROUP BY NAME ,datee
```

currently the result is:

[image]

BUT I need to add `sum` at the end.
So I tried with rollup:

```
 SELECT  Name,datee,SUM (val) 
    from @t GROUP BY NAME ,datee  with ROLLUP
```

[image]

BUT I only need the *last* sum total line.  I don't need the *in-report* `sum's`

So how can get the desire result?

(I cant change the  `group by` clause  cause others need it also , I just want to add sum at the end with/without rollup).

[sql online is here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/93333)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's possible with `GROUPING SETS`, try this:

```
SELECT  Name,datee,SUM (val) 
FROM    @t 
GROUP BY 
        GROUPING SETS((NAME ,datee), ())
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7868/0)

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're welcome, it's a standard TSQL feature, but it's not used that often (I guess) so people don't always know about it :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm sure you'll find resources about it online, I read about it in a book (although I can't really remember using it).

Comment: @RoyiNamir - The best explanation I have come across is by Itzik Ben Gan [part 1](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/grouping-sets-part-1-96805) and [part 2](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/grouping-sets-part-2-97007)

Comment: You can also find some examples and explanations in 'MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-433): Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Database Development', but it's a printed book.

Comment: Ivan , it seems that from now on I can forget about `group by a,b,c` and start doing `group by grouping sets(a,b,c)` as a preperation for future sum's ( if i ever need any)......right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I would use `GROUPING SETS` only when really needed. If ordinary `GROUP BY` satisfies your requirements, I would stick to it. I don't know if there is any performance difference between `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` and `GROUP BY col1, col2`... It depends on particular situation but I would tend do things the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 12):

It is also possible with `ROLLUP()`:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  datee,
  SUM (val) 
FROM @t 
GROUP BY 
  ROLLUP((NAME, datee))
;
```

`WITH ROLLUP`, as well as `WITH CUBE`, are non-standard and deprecated. (See *Non-ISO Compliant Syntax* in the [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) manual.)

It should be noted that `ROLLUP()` isn't supported in compatibility level under 90 in SQL Server 2005 or under 100 in SQL Server 2008+, while `GROUPING SETS()` is.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the final total, can't you just use a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT  Name,datee,SUM (val) 
from @t 
GROUP BY NAME ,datee 
union all
SELECT  null,null,SUM (val) 
from @t
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7861)

Or you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter the rows with the `null` values:

```
select name, 
  datee, 
  total
from
(
  SELECT  Name,datee,SUM (val) total
  from @t 
  GROUP BY NAME, datee with rollup
) src
where datee is not null
or
(
  name is null 
  and datee is null
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7866)

The result is:

```
|   NAME |      DATEE | COLUMN_2 |
----------------------------------
|      a | 2012-01-02 |      200 |
|      a | 2012-01-03 |      100 |
|      a | 2012-01-05 |      100 |
|      b | 2012-01-06 |      200 |
|      b | 2012-01-07 |      200 |
|      d | 2012-01-07 |      400 |
|      e | 2012-01-09 |      500 |
|      f | 2012-01-12 |      600 |
| (null) |     (null) |     2300 |
```

Comment: FYI @t is the result of a query. ( it doesnt matter) so ill have to write it twice. I did tried to do it with CTE but : http://i.stack.imgur.com/hYhOk.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well the second one, should work for that since there is no union all

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query :

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    Name ,
                    datee ,
                    SUM(val) summ
          FROM      @t
          GROUP BY  NAME ,
                    datee
                    WITH ROLLUP
        ) A
WHERE   ( datee IS NOT NULL
          OR ( datee IS NULL
               AND name IS NULL
             )
        )
```