# Display top three values and the sum of all other values

Tags: sql, sql-server

After I `ORDER BY cnt DESC` my results are

```
fld1  cnt
 A     9
 E     8
 D     6
 C     2
 B     2
 F     1
```

I need to have top 3 displayed and the rest to be summed as 'other', like this:

```
fld1  cnt
A      9
E      8
D      6
other  5
```

EDITED:

Thank you all for your input. Maybe it will help if you see the actual statement:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(u.FA AS VARCHAR(300)) AS FA,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN r.RT IN (1,11,12,17) THEN r.RT END) AS Jr,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN r.RT IN (3,4,13) THEN r.RT END) AS Bk,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN r.RT NOT IN (1,11,12,17,3,4,13) THEN r.RT END ) AS Other
FROM R r
    INNER JOIN DB..RTL rt
    ON r.RT = rt.RTID
    INNER JOIN U u
    ON r.UID = u.UID
WHERE rt.LC = 'en' 
GROUP BY CAST(u.FA AS VARCHAR(300))--FA is ntext
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

The produced result has 19 records. I need to show the top 5 and sum up the rest as "Other FA". I don't want to do a select from a select from a select with this kind of statement. I am more looking for some SQL function. Maybe ROW_NUMBER is good idea, but I don't know how exactly to apply it in this case.

Comment: You may want to look at the accepted solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478361/sum-with-sql-server-rollup-but-only-last-summary

Comment: @PM77-1 No. That question is different.

Comment: Your result set has 2 fields and your query has 5, and non of the fields of 1 are present in the other :P So I am unsure of the relation between both now...

Comment: You could adapt my solution if you replace `FROM @MyTable x` with a derivated table thus: `FROM (your query without ORDER BY) x` plus other changes.

Comment: The result set has also 5 fields. The initial 2 that I should are the ones that matter. I need the top 5 from the Total field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most direct way is to use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and then reaggreate them:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 3 then fld1 else 'Other' end) as fld1,
       sum(cnt) as cnt
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by fld1 order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then fld1 else 'Other' end);
```

You can actually do this as part of your original aggregation as well:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 3 then fld1 else 'Other' end) as fld1,
       sum(cnt) as cnt
from (select fld1, sum(...) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by fld1 order by sum(...) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by fld1
     ) t
group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then fld1 else 'Other' end);
```

EDIT (based on revised question):

```
select (case when seqnum <= 3 then FA else 'Other' end) as FA,
       sum(Total) as Total
from (SELECT CAST(u.FA AS VARCHAR(300)) AS FA,
             COUNT(*) AS Total,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY CAST(u.FA AS VARCHAR(300)) order by COUNT(*) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM R r
          INNER JOIN DB..RTL rt
          ON r.RT = rt.RTID
          INNER JOIN U u
          ON r.UID = u.UID
      WHERE rt.LC = 'en' 
      GROUP BY CAST(u.FA AS VARCHAR(300))--FA is ntext
     ) t
group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then FA else 'Other' end)
order by max(seqnum) desc;
```

The final `order by` keeps the records in ascending order by total.

Comment: Please see my edit. Can you help me fit ROW_NUMBER() into that statement. Thank you.

Comment: You have nothing called `fld1` in your statement

Comment: That was just a sample :). The FA is fld1, the Total is cnt

Answer (score 4):

Could be something like this:

```
select top 3 fld1, cnt from mytable
union
select 'Z - Other', sum(cnt) from mytable
where fld1 not in (select top 3 fld1 from mytable order by fld1)
order by fld1
```

(Updated to include order by)

Comment: Yup, thought about this as well, but kept with OP structure. I'd add ORDER BY too

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: "super succint" **doens't means** (always) the best solution.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean agree, and I voted for your answer too, but I like this better. Easier to read, and less nested queries. If the ordering is important use a CTE.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: i-one has signaled **a small** problem with this solution: all those SELECT TOP(3) ... FROM mytable doesn't have an ORDER BY.

Comment: OK, I will add them just to avoid confusion

Comment: The logical order of execution is UNION and then ORDER BY. First SELECT needs an ORDER BY before UNION.

Comment: Not necessarily if the second select guaranteed to be sorted last. In that example I artificially set name to "Z..." but there're other means (additional sort field etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select fld1,cnt from test
where cnt in(select top 3 cnt from test)
union
select 'Other', sum(cnt)from test
where cnt not in (select top 3 cnt from test)
order by cnt desc;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2437c/18)

Answer (score -2):

I`m not sure how "first" and skip clauses should be used in SQLServer 
but in firebird this works but i think it could be modified to run on SQLServer

```
    select first 3 p.fld1,p.cnt from Table p
    union
    select t."others",sum(t.cnt )  from (
    select skip 3 'others' as "others",p.cnt from Table p
    ) as t
    group by "others"
```