# How to group by a param but also include the total aggregated (ungrouped by)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, rollup

I have a table in Postgres 9.3.6 that looks like this:

```
utm_source    value
fb            12
fb            8
google        3
google        4
null          5
```

I want to run a SQL query to sum `value` by `utm_source`, but also include the total value as well. So the final table should look like:

```
utm_source    sum
fb            20
google        7
null          5
all           32
```

This is what I'd otherwise use:

```
SELECT SUM(value) as sum FROM my_table GROUP BY utm_source;
```

But I want the `all` in there as well!

Comment: ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS are some options, and has several options covered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14478361/84206

Comment: Please tag your DBMS as there may be solutions that are platform specific.

Comment: It is postgres 9.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) so the base table is only scanned once, which is typically faster. There is some overhead cost for the CTE, so it may not pay for trivially small tables.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT utm_source, sum(value) AS sum_value
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL  -- not just UNION !
SELECT 'all', sum(sum_value) FROM cte;
```

SQL Server has a non-standard extension for the task using the `grouping()` and `rollup()` keywords. Here is how to implement it in Postgres:

- [Grouping() equivalent in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/94817/3684)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT isnull(utm_source,'')
       ,SUM(value) as sum 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY isnull(utm_source,'') with rollup
```

you can update the NULL to 'all' later.

Comment: The OP did not clarify the RDBMS at first. It's Postgres, `rollup` is a non-standard feature of SQL Server and does not work in Postgres. Details: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/grouping-equivalent-in-postgresql/94822#94822