# Average Column-wise by using T-sql and Pivot

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have developed Financial Year Data Fiscal year wise Till now i have achieved! But i couldn't get column-wise average

My table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblact] (
    [Id]                 INT             NOT NULL,
    [years]              NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [months]             NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [expenses]           DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [closingbal]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [monthorder]         INT             NULL
```

**My Query**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE fiscalyear 
AS
DECLARE @qstr AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT  @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(years)FROM (SELECT DISTINCT years FROM tblact) AS years;
    SET @qstr ='SELECT months, ' + @ColumnName + ',total,average  FROM 
    (SELECT months, years, expenses,avg(expenses) over(partition by months) average,sum(expenses) over (partition by months) total ,monthorder FROM tblact ) AS p 
    PIVOT(SUM(expenses) FOR  years  IN (' + @ColumnName + '))  AS PVTTable order by monthorder  ';
    EXEC sp_executesql  @qstr
```

Kindly please do help to acheive the answer

My output Now :

```
Months | 2009-2010 | 2010 - 2011 | 2012-2013 | Total | Average
--------------------------------------------------------------
April  | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 9000  |  3000
MAY    | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 9000  |  3000
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output

```
Months | 2009-2010 | 2010 - 2011 | 2012-2013 | Total | Average
--------------------------------------------------------------
April  | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 9000  |  3000
MAY    | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 9000  |  3000
--------------------------------------------------------------
Average| 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 9000  |  3000
```

Kindly Help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478361/sum-with-sql-server-rollup-but-only-last-summary

Comment: I couldn't figure our where i can add the query i understand i need to use ROLLUP by where should i add , Kindly Help!

Comment: Store the results of your current query in a table variable, and then the averages will simply be the SUM divided by the COUNT of each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. I simply use a UNION ALL and AVG your columns. Note: I use 13 as the month order for the 'Average' row so when it's ordered, it goes at the end. If you need anything else let me know.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fiscalyear 
AS
DECLARE @qstr           NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnName     NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @AvgColumnName  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(years),
        @AvgColumnName = COALESCE(@AvgColumnName + ',','') + 'AVG(' + QUOTENAME(years) + ')'
FROM tblact 
GROUP BY years;

SET @qstr ='
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT months, ' + @ColumnName + ',total,average,monthorder  FROM 
    (SELECT months, years, expenses,avg(expenses) over(partition by months) average,sum(expenses) over (partition by months) total ,monthorder FROM tblact ) AS p 
    PIVOT(SUM(expenses) FOR  years  IN (' + @ColumnName + '))  AS PVTTable
),
CTE_Average
AS
(
SELECT months, ' + @ColumnName +',total,average,monthorder
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Average'',' + @AvgColumnName + ',AVG(total),AVG(average),13
FROM CTE
)

SELECT months,' + @ColumnName + ',total,average
FROM CTE_Average
ORDER BY monthOrder'

EXEC sp_executesql  @qstr
```

Comment: Stephan : Thank you soo much ! Was sitting on it for last three days! The code is absolute!

Comment: Mr. Stephan., Is there anyway i could hide monthorder column in my output?

Comment: You need it to sort the data so I just added CTE_Average and select from that instead. Check it out