# Get Previous Column and Duplicate with (Coloumn Row Index) Value if NULL using T-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have developed Financial Year Data Fiscal year wise, But When a new Fiscal year is started Say April of 2015-2016 financial year is entered , remaining rows are NUll in that particular year , i dont want that, i need previous year values to be shown instead of NULL

**MY Query**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblact] (
    [Id]                 INT             NOT NULL,
    [years]              NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [months]             NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [expenses]           DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [closingbal]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [monthorder]         INT             NULL
```

**My T-sql**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fiscalyear 
AS
DECLARE @qstr           NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnName     NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @AvgColumnName  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(years),
        @AvgColumnName = COALESCE(@AvgColumnName + ',','') + 'AVG(' + QUOTENAME(years) + ')'
FROM tblact 
GROUP BY years;

SET @qstr ='
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT months, ' + @ColumnName + ',total,average,monthorder  FROM 
    (SELECT months, years, expenses,avg(expenses) over(partition by months) average,sum(expenses) over (partition by months) total ,monthorder FROM tblact ) AS p 
    PIVOT(SUM(expenses) FOR  years  IN (' + @ColumnName + '))  AS PVTTable
)

SELECT months, ' + @ColumnName +',total,average,monthorder
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Average'',' + @AvgColumnName + ',AVG(total),AVG(average),13
FROM CTE
ORDER BY monthorder;'

EXEC sp_executesql  @qstr
```

**My Output**

```
Months | 2012-2013 | 2013 - 2014 | 2014-2015 |2015-2016 | Total | Average
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
April  | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 4500     | 9000  |  3000
MAY    | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | NULL     | 9000  |  3000
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average| 2000      | 3000        | 4000      |  4500    | 9000  |  3000
```

**My Expected Output**
 To get Previous Fiscal Year (i.e, 2014-2015 May Value in 2015-2016 May row if NULL)

```
Months | 2012-2013 | 2013 - 2014 | 2014-2015 |2015-2016 | Total | Average
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
April  | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 4500     | 9000  |  3000
MAY    | 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | *4000*     | 9000  |  3000
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average| 2000      | 3000        | 4000      | 4250    | 9000  |  3000
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: this is possible duplcate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894263/average-column-wise-by-using-t-sql-and-pivot?noredirect=1#comment47912485_29894263

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or an SQLFiddle to test this with? I'm pretty confident I can get the result you want, but I don't really have time to sift through the outputs to create some working sample data.

Answer (score 1):

without the pivot

```
select [yearThis].[years], [yearThis].[months]
     , isnull([yearThis].[expenses], [yearLast].[expenses]) 
  from [tblact] as [yearThis] 
  left join [tblact] as [yearLast] 
    on [yearLast].[years]  = [yearThis].[yearThis] - 1 
   and [yearLast].[months] = [yearThis].[months]
```